# how to uninstall shopware plugin manually

Tags: shopware

I tried to install a Shopware plugin via the backend (plugin page).

After clicking on download and entering my Shopware login data, the following error message appears immediately:

```
An error has occurred on the SBP server.
Error code: OrdersException-2
```

I wanted to install it again and change my last input.
But now the same error message appears immediately and ends my attempt immediately.

It is not listed in the backend (plugin page).

**How do I get this plugin uninstalled completely clean?**

*I have FTP access.*

*I using shopware Version 5.4.6*

[DSGVO Kit Lite](https://store.shopware.com/sysg961328677932f/dsgvo-kit-lite-datenschutzhinweise-mit-checkboxen.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gess you deleted it after deinstallation, so it isn't on your server any more (and therefore not listed in the plugin-manager). In this case you need the zip file of the plugin. It can be downloaded via your shopware account (account.shopware.com) and you can upload the zipfile directly to your plugin-manager. This would be the easiest way if the login issues persists in your plugin-manager.

Comment: I did not deleted and i not deinstalled it. So maybe it never was completly installed? Ans so its maybe not on the server . I found nothing like this in /engine/Shopware/Plugins/Community/Frontend .

Comment: Instead of DSGVO Kit Lite I now use the following settings:
Settings> Preferences> Privacy> Privacy checkbox to true.
It works. I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can try delete the plugin with ssh (for this command you need to be in the shopware dir ofcourse):

```
php bin/console sw:plugin:delete {plugin name}
```

If this doesn't work, you can try to delete the plugin in the database. You can find the plugin in the table `s_core_plugins`. If deleted here it should be gone.